# Is there a way to add a list item to a specific place in google docs?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that creates a copy of a google doc when a form is submitted, and has find and replace functionality based on the form submitted. Currently I have a list of items from a checklist that I find and replace but I'd like to shift it to append so I don't end up with excess items in a list left without being replaced.

Currently when script is run it'll fill in what can be filled:

Processes to work

1. example process 1 from google form
2. example process 2 from google form
3. {{process3}}
4. {{process4}}
5. {{process5}}

I'd like if possible, to be able to avoid find and replace and be able to append to this list instead. My issue is that this list is in a specific location and I'd like to call to the index of it and then append at that point. I'm fairly new to writing any kind of code.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your `Processes to work`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Of course! "Process to work" is just the PARAGRAPH in the google doc to label the list

Comment: Did you try to implement the suggested solution?

Comment: Yes. I was able to use body.insertListItem using the index I had on the document. My other question now is, is there a way to append a child to the list item?

For example:
1. the list item
     a. the list item I want to instert/append

Comment: You gave no reaction for days on the useful and correct answer, then just ask a new question as a comment that unlikely will be read by somebody ever. Well, I doubt you will get the answer any time soon. Good luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how you can append a new item at the end of existed list in your document:

```
function append_item_at_the_end_of_a_list() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var list = body.getListItems().pop();        // get the last list item
  var index = body.getChildIndex(list)+1;      // get index of the item
  body.insertListItem(index, 'New list item'); // append a new list item at the end
}
```

The code supposes that the document has just one list or the wanted list is a last one. If you have several lists and the modified list is not the last one it needs a more complicated solution.